# Lebesgue integral of a ratio of Lebesgue densities

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need a hint to solve the following problem:

$P$ is a probability mass on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ with a Lebesgue density $h$, $f$ is another Lebesgue density. I need to show that $\int \frac{h(x)}{f(x)}dP \ge 1$.

Comment: What is a Lebesgue density?

Comment: if $P(A)=\int_A f(x)\lambda(x)$ $ \forall A \in \mathcal B^1$, then $f(x)$ is a Lebesgue density for $P$

Comment: So, there are two probability measures, $P$ and $P'$ and $h=\frac{dP}{d\lambda}$ and $f=\frac{dP'}{d\lambda}$. Formally, then $\frac hf = \frac{dP}{dP'}$. Then I don't understand why $\int \frac{dP}{dP'}dP\ge 1.$ If it was $\int \frac fh dP$ then $\int \frac fh dP=\int \frac{dP'}{dP}dP=\int dP'=1.$

Comment: @zoli I think you flipped the ratio at some point in your comment, you do the calculation for $\int \frac fh dP$ and conclude that it is 1 (rightfully so), but I am trying to show that $\int \frac hf dP = \int \frac{h^2}{f} d \lambda \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int\frac{h}{f}\,{\rm d}P=\int\frac{h^{2}}{f}\,{\rm d}\lambda,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

But by Cauchy Schwarz, we have
$$
1=\int h\,{\rm d}\lambda=\int\frac{h}{\sqrt{f}}\cdot\sqrt{f}\,{\rm d}\lambda\leq\sqrt{\int\frac{h^{2}}{f}\,{\rm d}\lambda}\cdot\sqrt{\int f\,{\rm d}\lambda}=\sqrt{\int\frac{h^{2}}{f}\,{\rm d}\lambda}=\sqrt{\int\frac{h}{f}\,{\rm d}P}.
$$
The only slight problem (which I leave to you) is discussion of why there is no problem with
dividing by zero, i.e. $\frac{h\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{f\left(x\right)}}$
does not make sense if $f\left(x\right)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! In my application actually $h >0$ and $f>0$. I actually would not now why it would be OK to divide by 0. One can say that $\frac{a}{0}=\infty, a \in \mathbb R$, but then we have another problem when $f=0$ and $h=0$. Also one can not argue that $\lambda(\{f=0,h=0\})=0$, i.e $f \ne 0$ and $h \ne 0$ almost everywhere. So I am confused